# How to un-inline an inline class?

Tags: android

As a bloody android beginner I am trying to put an inline class definition into its proper class. Here is the piece of code with the inline class:

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // actual code here
    }
});
```

Here is what I have tried but gives a compiler error:

```
public class TestClass extends View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // actual code here
    }
}
```

Error message: `no interface expected here`. I have no idea what this text means...

So how to proper un-inline an inline class, so that I can use it as follows in the actual code:

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new TestClass());
```

Comment: Android and Java beginner?

Comment: Yes bloody beginner in both. Less than 10 years experience! Maybe in 10 years I know the basics...

Comment: I see.. Maybe not that long! Personally, Java 2 years, Android 1 year. But yeah, these "inline" classes are called [anonymous classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) and you `implements` an [`interface`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html) and [`extends`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/inheritance.html) a [`class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/class.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is issue in implementation

In java class must be `extend` and interface must be `implements`

`View.OnClickListener` is an interface so implement it.

> Sample correct code

```
public class TestMe implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // actual code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Because `View.OnClickListener` is an interface but not a class?